# Quicker way to process multiple SUBSTRING_INDEX mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that inserts 4 fields into a table. I have to substring index's on 2 of those fields.

This is my query that works but takes a while. Any tips to speed up?

```
INSERT INTO tblmatch (subactivity_user,activity_user,activity_result,subactivity_result)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.activity,'/',1), a.activity, b.activity,SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.activity,'/',1)
FROM tbluser a, results b
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.activity,'/',1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.activity,'/',1) 
AND a.activity NOT IN( b.activity)
```

This is how the tblmatch is created

```
CREATE TABLE tblmatch (
subactivity_user varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
activity_user varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
activity_result varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
subactivity_result varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
INDEX activity_result (activity_result))
```

This is results table setup

```
CREATE TABLE results (
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
activity varchar(250) NOT NULL,
count int(6) NOT NULL,
countlast int(6) NOT NULL,
INDEX activity (activity),
UNIQUE INDEX activity_2 (activity)
)
```

Here is an example of the data im getting from text file.

```
    <item component="ComponentInfo{au.com.phil.abduction2.demo/au.com.phil.abduction2.demo.menus.PsymIntro}" drawable="abduction" />
```

Here is how im originally getting the data.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$ptmpName' 
INTO TABLE tbluser 
LINES STARTING BY '{' 
TERMINATED BY '\" />' (@name,@activity) 
set name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'\"',-1),
activity=SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'}',1)
```

This is tbluser setup

```
CREATE TABLE tbluser (
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
activity varchar(200) NOT NULL,
INDEX activity (activity)
)
```

**UPDATE**
I updated my tbluser and original methoed of getting data to this. Would this be a good setup for the table?

```
CREATE TABLE tbluser (
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
activity_full varchar(200) NOT NULL,
activity varchar(100) NOT NULL,
class varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (activity_full),
UNIQUE INDEX activity (activity_full))
```

Here is my new query to get data from txt file

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$ptmpName' 
    INTO TABLE tbluser 
    LINES STARTING BY '{' 
    TERMINATED BY '\" />' 
    (@name,@activity_full,@activity,@class) 
    set 
    name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'\"',-1),
    activity_full=SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'}',1),
    activity=SUBSTRING_INDEX(activity_full,'/',-1),
    class=SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'/',1)"
```

Comment: After looking at the processed data it seems i am getting duplicates in my activity_user and activity_results somehow

Comment: looks like you have some serious issues with your database design.. you need to have a primary unique key for each table and foreign keys... can you also post some data?

Comment: Do you have lists of values separated by the slash in your columns named `activity`. That's almost ever not a good idea. One drawback is that it's difficult to get a certain value and that you can't use indexes. It's only normal that performance suffers with such a table design. But my guess may be wrong.

Comment: updated question with more details. Thank you for any help

Comment: I concur with Vmai: split out a `tbl_users_(sub)activies`, with only 1 (sub)actvity per row, and index that.

Comment: okay. SO... this is what i should be doing. The tblresults table should have a primary key on activity and a foreign key on activity that references a new tblresults_activity activity_full. then in tblresults_activity it should set activity_full as primary key and activity, class columns can do the SUBSTRING_INDEX to fill them. is that right?